How can I set a widget height based on its child in flutter?
I have a Container. Inside this I have a column (children of this column are expanded, align and contianer). I want to set my container's height based on column's height, also when user clicks on add button it add a widget to my column. I have made this using Global key but when column's height changes my container's height dose not change. what should I do?
I have tried Global key and Layout Builder but Layout builder gives me null and global key gives me a not real value.
